# timer for every table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i want to add a notification for every table row after 10 minutes,
  starting time of the counter will be based on the entry time on the database.

```
Sample Table  
ID     |    Item     |    EntryTime   |    Status     |
-------------------------------------------------------------  
101    |    Fries    |    19:20:12    |    Active     |Alert Goes Here  
102    |    burger   |    22:23:14    |    Active     |Alert Goes Here  

if 101 timer is over 10 Minutes, an alert or notification would appear.
```

I need your help guys, thank you very much and appreciate it so much.
  i can do it in pure php by using page refresh for a certain time,
  but that i think that consume resources

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly implementation, but assuming you can handle writing an `addAlertToRow` function... this should at least get you on the right track

```
<table>
<? foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr id="<?=$row['id'];?>">
        <td><?=$row['id'];?></td>
         ...
        <td><span class="alert"></span>
            <script>
                (function() {
                    var ten_minutes = 600000; //milliseconds
                    var now = <?=time() * 1000;?>;
                    var entryTime= <?php echo strtotime($entryTime)*1000; ?>;
                    var timeAgo = now - entryTime; //how long ago was the entry added
                    setTimeout(function() { 
                        var row = document.getElementById('<?=$row['id'];?>');
                        addAlertToRow(row);
                    }, ten_minutes - timeAgo);
                 })();
             </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
</table>
```